# Why does Bit-Shifting a Bit-Shifted byte result in different values depending on order of shifting?

Tags: java, casting, bit-manipulation, byte, bit-shift

Consider this Java code:

```
    byte a = (byte) 0b01111110; //Binary Literal
    byte b1 = (byte) (a << 1);
    byte c1 = (byte) (a >> 1);
    byte b2 = (byte) (b1 >> 1);
    byte c2 = (byte) (c1 << 1);
    System.out.println("A:" + a + " B1:" + b1 + " C1:" + c1 + " B2:" + b2 + " C2:" + c2);
```

The resulting output is:

```
A:126 B1:-4 C1:63 B2:-2 C2:126
```

Why does the byte 'b2' have a value not equal to that of 'a' (and 'c2' in this case) even though neither shift causes a binary digit to get dropped?

Comment: Because you have overflowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of sign extension. Use `>>>` to prevent that:

```
byte a = (byte) 0b01111110; // 0b01111110 = 126
byte b1 = (byte) (a << 1);  // 0b11111100 =  -4  <-- overflow
byte c1 = (byte) (a >> 1);  // 0b00111111 =  63
byte b2 = (byte) (b1 >> 1); // 0b11111110 =  -2  <-- sign extension
byte c2 = (byte) (c1 << 1); // 0b01111110 = 126

byte x = (byte) (b1 >>> 1); // 0b01111110 = 126  <-- no sign extension
```

Also, your statement "even though neither shift causes a binary digit to get dropped" is incorrect. All shift operations *will* drop a digit. In your case the dropped digits just happen to be zero.

Answer (score -1):

> ...neither shift causes a binary digit to get dropped

#### False.

All shift operations will cause digits to be dropped. By dumb luck, what you've observed only appears to disprove this because `0` bits are being dropped. I think your question has to with [sign extensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension), and understanding **arithmetic shifts** (`>>` and `<<`, vs. **logical shifts** (`>>>`). When performing **arithmetic shifts**, the sign bit is extended to preserve the a number's signedness.

To quote Java's [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html):

> The signed left shift operator "<<" shifts a bit pattern to the left,
> and the signed right shift operator ">>" shifts a bit pattern to the
> right. The bit pattern is given by the left-hand operand, and the
> number of positions to shift by the right-hand operand. The unsigned
> right shift operator ">>>" shifts a zero into the leftmost position,
> while the leftmost position after ">>" depends on sign extension.

Comment: I don't think it was "dumb luck", that's just you assumption, and very judgmental. --- Java doesn't have a `<<<` operator.

Comment: [Dump luck](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/dumb-luck): "The way in which something good happens completely **by chance**, without being planned or deserved". You are *assuming* it was by chance, not deliberate. And from you link, synonyms: Fluke, Happenstance. Less judgmental by not using the word "dumb".

Comment: If you carefully reread his question, you'll see it _was_ dumb luck that caused those variables to match: binary zeros were shifted off. In any event, I'm not going to argue semantics of the English language on this site, so feel free to post another comment -- I'll ignore it.